# Haproxy nbsrv acl not working

Tags: haproxy, access-control-list

The following acl doesn't work for me:

```
acl no_waf nbsrv(to_waf) lt 1
use_backend back-www if no_waf
default_backend to_waf
```

I keep getting error 503 (No server is available to handle this request.) instead of being sent to the backend back-www.

Any ideas?

**EDIT, backend to_waf looks like this:

backend         to_waf

```
    option  forwardfor header X-Forwarded-For

    option  httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.0

    http-check expect status 404

    timeout server 25s

    server  10.30.10.2:9000    10.30.10.2:9000    check
```

Comment: Do you have health checks configured on the servers in `to_waf`?  If not, HAProxy has no real option but to assume they are up and fail when it turns out that they aren't.

Comment: Yes, my backend looks like this:backend         to_waf
        option  forwardfor header X-Forwarded-For
        option  httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.0
        http-check expect status 404
        timeout server 25s
        server  10.30.10.2:9000    10.30.10.2:9000    check

Comment: What do you see in the HAProxy logs?

Comment: localhost haproxy[29072]: Server to_waf/10.30.10.2:9000 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
Jan 12 19:48:27 localhost haproxy[29072]: backend to_waf has no server available!

Answer (score 0):

Found it: I was reloading haproxy and there was a error in the config file, for some reason reloading it didn't trigger any error message. When I tried to restart the service I got the error, after fixing it the condition started to work.